# Java asks for two numbers instead of 1

Tags: java

This program is working towards separating negative, odd, and even integers. When compiled, it asks the user for 2 numbers instead of one, and breaks. How do I fix it from asking for 2 numbers.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Integer{
public static void main(String [] args){
    Scanner reader = new Scanner (System.in);

    double number;  
    int count = 0;
    double [] evenList = new double[count];
    double [] oddList = new double[count];
    double [] negativeList = new double[count];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        System.out.println("Please enter an integer: ");
        number = reader.nextDouble();
        count++; 

        if (number < 0) {
            negativeList[i] = reader.nextDouble();
        }
        if (number % 2 == 0) {
            evenList[i] = reader.nextDouble();
        } else {
            oddList[i] = reader.nextDouble();
        }     
    }

    System.out.println("Negatives: " + Arrays.toString(negativeList));
    System.out.println("Odds: " + Arrays.toString(oddList));
    System.out.println("Evens: " + Arrays.toString(evenList));
}
}
```

Comment: I see a code path that does guarantee that two numbers will be asked for.  You always ask for one number, but you will ask for another number if the one you entered prior is even or odd.  What are you trying to do with the `number` variable, and what are you intending to fill `negativeList[i]`, `evenList[i]`, and `oddList[i]` with?

Comment: You should put the value in the `number` variable to any of your lists instead of using `reader.nextDouble()` the second time inside your loop.

Comment: i would like to have the arrays be filled with numbers and then have them be outputted in the end when the negatives, evens, and odds are sorted

Comment: it gives me an arrayoutofbendsexception 0 when entering the first integer after using the solutions below this

Answer (score 1):

You are reading again value from scanner inside `if` block. Use `number` instead

```
    if (number < 0) {
        negativeList[i] = number;
    }
    if (number % 2 == 0) {
        evenList[i] = number;
    } else {
        oddList[i] = number;
    }
```

Comment: its gives me an array break

Comment: You need to initialize `count` to some > 0 value, you can't increase array size in a loop like that. Put something like this `int count = 10;`

Answer (score 1):

change this :

```
if ( number < 0 ) {
    negativeList [ i ] = reader . nextDouble ( ) ;
}

if ( number % 2 == 0 ) {
    evenList [ i ] = reader . nextDouble ( ) ;
} 
else {
    oddList [ i ] = reader . nextDouble ( ) ;
}
```

to this :

```
if ( number < 0 ) {
    negativeList [ i ] = number ;
}

if ( number % 2 == 0 ) {
    evenList [ i ] = number ;
} 
else {
    oddList [ i ] = number ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want this:

```
number = reader.nextDouble(); // read the number using Scanner once
count++; 

// use it to futher to add to respective arrays
if (number < 0) {
    negativeList[i] = number;
}
if (number % 2 == 0) {
    evenList[i] = number;
} else {
    oddList[i] = number;
}
```